# Is it possible to loop through sapgui array using a for next loop in excel vba?

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I would like to loop through and read back the text boxes of each element in SAP GUI table/array:

```
dim Rtned_Desc as string

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS_ITOV/tabpTCMA/ssubSUBPAGE:SAPLCSDI:0152/tblSAPLCSDITCMAT/ctxtRC29P-IDNRK[2,0]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS_ITOV/tabpTCMA/ssubSUBPAGE:SAPLCSDI:0152/tblSAPLCSDITCMAT/ctxtRC29P-IDNRK[2,0]").caretPosition = 9
Rtned_Desc = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS_ITOV/tabpTCMA/ssubSUBPAGE:SAPLCSDI:0152/tblSAPLCSDITCMAT/ctxtRC29P-IDNRK[2,0]").Text

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS_ITOV/tabpTCMA/ssubSUBPAGE:SAPLCSDI:0152/tblSAPLCSDITCMAT/ctxtRC29P-IDNRK[2,1]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS_ITOV/tabpTCMA/ssubSUBPAGE:SAPLCSDI:0152/tblSAPLCSDITCMAT/ctxtRC29P-IDNRK[2,1]").caretPosition = 9
Rtned_Desc = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS_ITOV/tabpTCMA/ssubSUBPAGE:SAPLCSDI:0152/tblSAPLCSDITCMAT/ctxtRC29P-IDNRK[2,1]").Text

etc...
```

I'd like to do a "for next" loop, something like this:

```
for index = 0 to 10

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS_ITOV/tabpTCMA/ssubSUBPAGE:SAPLCSDI:0152/tblSAPLCSDITCMAT/ctxtRC29P-IDNRK[2,index]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS_ITOV/tabpTCMA/ssubSUBPAGE:SAPLCSDI:0152/tblSAPLCSDITCMAT/ctxtRC29P-IDNRK[2,index]").caretPosition = 9
Rtned_Desc = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS_ITOV/tabpTCMA/ssubSUBPAGE:SAPLCSDI:0152/tblSAPLCSDITCMAT/ctxtRC29P-IDNRK[2,index]).Text

next
```

I have been trying to escape the 'index' variable, but have failed. Is this the right approach?

Comment: In fact, your VBA question is about building a string variable based on a text and another variable?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
for index = 0 to 10

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS_ITOV/tabpTCMA/ssubSUBPAGE:SAPLCSDI:0152/tblSAPLCSDITCMAT/ctxtRC29P-IDNRK[2," & cstr(index) & "]").SetFocus
'It is not necessarily needed.
'session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS_ITOV/tabpTCMA/ssubSUBPAGE:SAPLCSDI:0152/tblSAPLCSDITCMAT/ctxtRC29P-IDNRK[2,index]").caretPosition = 9
Rtned_Desc = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS_ITOV/tabpTCMA/ssubSUBPAGE:SAPLCSDI:0152/tblSAPLCSDITCMAT/ctxtRC29P-IDNRK[2," & cstr(index) & "]").Text

next
```

Regards, ScriptMan